# How can I call a codebehind function from JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a JavaScript function which i call in the onchange handler of a dropdownlist. If the selected value of dropdownlist is "1" i want to call one function in codebehind.
Following is the  function in JavaScript:

```
function  GetAdmissionType()
    {
        InitComponents();
        var type="";
        type=document.getElementById(dlAdmissionType.id).value;
        document.getElementById(hdnAdmissionType.id).value=document.getElementById(dlAdmissionType.id).value;
        if(type=="1")
        {
        }
  }
```

If type is 1 then i want to work following code in codebehind

```
public void LoadSemesters()
{
   //code to load other dropdownlists
}
```

Can anybody help to call function in codebehind from JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to expose the codebehind function as a web service call and use something like jQuery to call it from Javascript.

Comment: Can you provide an example or give us a link?

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on what you want to do with the other values in the drop-down list. But, the easiest way to do this is to wrap your drop-down list in an update panel and handle the OnSelectedIndexChanged event in your code-behind.

ASPX page:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">item 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">item 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">item 3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">item 4</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "1":
            LoadSemesters();
            break;
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
        default:
            // do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Then you wouldn't need to do any javascript processing (unless you wanted to).

Answer (score 0):

please see this post 
http://usmanshabbir.blogspot.com/2009/10/simplest-way-to-call-server-side.html

Comment: Why not link directly to the article instead of to a blog full of ads?

Comment: im sorry i just did it cos i had saved the link to my own blog and it was easier for me to search my own blog offline (I use windows live writer) instead of the actual blog.